# How to print voltages side by side?

Tags: python, printing

I'm using a program that prints out voltages one right below the other, like:

```
2.333

2.334

2.336

2.445
```

But I want it like:

```
2.333 2.334 2.336 2.445
```

## Ok, here is what works for me:

```
while True:
   voltsdiff = adc.readADCDifferential01(4096, 8)
   import sys
   print '{:.4f}'.format(voltsdiff),
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Append commna(`,`) at the end of the `print` statement: `print "%.4f" % (voltsdiff),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have answered, to print output without a newline in Python 2, put a comma at the end of your print statement:

```
print "%.4f" % voltsdiff,
```

However, this will not flush the output, as standard output is line buffered by default (it will only be flushed when a newline is added to the output). There are a few ways you can fix that.

First, you could, at some point, append a newline with just a basic `print` statement, e.g.:

```
for i, voltsdiffs in enumerate(many_voltages):
    print "%.4f" % voltsdiffs,
    if i % 10 == 9:
         print # puts a newline after every 10 values
```

Next, you could explicitly flush standard output, using `sys.stdout.flush()`:

```
print "%.4f" % voltsdiffs,
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Finally, you can use the Python 3 style `print` function, which has a `flush` parameter (which does the flushing for you, if it is `True`):

```
# before any other code
from __future__ import print_function

# later
print(format(voltsdiffs, ".4f"), end=" ", flush=True)
```

I'd generally recommend the last version, as it's what you'll need to use in the future if you port your code to Python 3. It's also quite explicit, with each special characteristic of the printing (no newline at the end, flushing automatically) called for by a separate keyword argument.

Comment: @Rico: If my answer helped solve your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 2):

Just print them with a comma

```
print "%.4f" % (voltsdiff),
```

Moreover, you might want to use `format` method. You can read all about formatting [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

```
print "{:.4f}".format(voltsdiff),
```

Lets say, you are printing these values by iterating a list, you can do something like this

```
data = [2.333, 2.334, 2.336, 2.445]
print " ".join(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print to terminal, you may use stdout with **\r or \b** escape

```
sys.stdout.write("\r%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%.4f" % (v1, v2, v3, v4))
```

The "\r" escape move the cursor at begining of line (like cr on same line) and "\b" is untab: move 4 position back.

P.S.:stdout do some cache, you should call sys.stdout.flush() to be sure that the result is on terminal at request, before the buffer is full